# PDO fetchAll takes a long time

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using PDO to get the results from my MySQL db.

If I'm only doing the execute statement it takes about `8 seconds`. (doing the same thing 350 times in a row.)

When adding a `fetchAll()` statement it goes up to **28 seconds**. Is this normal behavior?

I did a network test speed between the web server and the db server, its around `87 Mbits/sec` so that cannot be the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: I am curious, how many rows does it fetch?

Comment: Can't you find a way to process the resultset record-by-record and save yourself having to allocate memory in PHP for the full thing?

Comment: agreed with @eggyal - fetchAll is incredibly inefficient; for most uses it's better to loop through the dataset fetching one record at a time.

Comment: I would have thought execute would have been better to use overall anyway as its more efficient and is safer (allows binding of params which removes user requirement to escape or quote the params).

Comment: Are you providing a `LIMIT` clause in your `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 1):

8 seconds for the execute is also ridiculously long - and the indicates that you don't have the table correctly indexed. As a result, it's taking a very long time to get the data from the table. It's possibly also using a temporary table.

Make sure that you have any fields used in a "search" or that are used as a search key in joined tables indexed. Indexes are a bit tricky to get right - but to test, add "EXPLAIN" before your query and print out the results from that - you'll get a row per table. If you have any "using WHERE" or "create temporary tables" then these are probably what you need to remove by adding indexes on those tables.